# Connecting selenium driver to browser that is embedded in an application

Tags: python, selenium

I want to use Selenium WebDriver to run automated tests in a browser that is embedded in an application

[image]
I write code like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

TOOL_LOCATION = r"C:\my_app\app.exe"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location = TOOL_LOCATION

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://test-dev:4444/wd/hub',
                      desired_capabilities=chrome_options.to_capabilities())

driver.find_element_by_name("input")
time.sleep(1)
driver.close()
```

When i start my test i'm getting following error:

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the browser version and chromedriver version as a first thing.

or,
You need to Add --disable-dev-shm-usage to default launch flags. check the url

[ However as per Add --disable-dev-shm-usage to default launch flags seems adding the argument --disable-dev-shm-usage will temporary solve the issue.]

url: [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t)